# How to pass DataTable from one class to the other class

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

currently i'm studying MySQL, sorry for my newbie question. Here my question

I have 2 class, the first one is Windows Form, and the other is just a class which I want contain all processes from SQL. here's my code in SQL Class

```
public void SampleQuery(string tablename)
    {
        DataTable dataTable;

        string query = "SELECT * FROM " + tablename;

        //Open connection
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query,connection);

            dataTable =  new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dataTable);

            //close Connection
            this.CloseConnection();
            return;
        }
```

What I want to do is, show the data from SQL with DataGridView.
Is it possible to code the datagridview in SQL Class above? or must be in Windows Form part?

if must be in windows form, how to throw the dataTable which is now hold all the data to Windows Form class?

thanks a lot for helping me. If my question sounds absurd just ask me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DataGrid` `DataSource` property.

Sample code demontrate idea:

```
class MyForm : Form
{
   public MyForm()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      DataAccess  dataAccess = new DataAccess();
      m_dataGrid.DataSource = DataAccess.SampleQuery("MyTable");
   }
}

class DataAccess 
{
   public DataTable SampleQuery(string tablename)
   {
      DataTable dataTable;
      // 
      // Your Code
      // ..
      return dataTable;
   }
}
```

I think is Form Load event handler is good place to load data (not constructor ;) as i show above). You may olso implement some caching (load datatable each time if form is open is not efficient:))

Comment: the first part in form class? and the second part in sql class?

Comment: Yes, MyForm is your Form class and DataAccess is your data access layer.

Comment: thanks alot guys...btw, why is my SampleQuery is red underlined and it says "not all paths code is returns a value" ?

Comment: Probobly because you return is inside if statement => you should return outside if.

Comment: yeah, i already tried that but the return dataTable says something like, use of unassigned variable. but at the top I already declare it.

Comment: Data Access is class (or group of class) that comunicates directly with your data storage (database) and your ui comunicate with that class not directly with database. When for example you change database engine (you change code only inside DAL class) UI is invariant.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `SampleQuery` method return the `dataTable`:

```
public DataTable SampleQuery(string tablename) {
    // Fill dataTable...
    return dataTable
}
```

Then call the method in your form and bind the `dataTable` to the `dataGridView`:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = SampleQuery("MyTable");
```

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, you would changethe method to return DataTable instead of nothing (void), and end with

```
return dataTable;
```

Then catch it when you call it:

```
DataGridView.BindingSource = yourDal.SimpleQuery("Foo");
```

Personally I would suggest class-based objects rather than DataTable, but DataTable will work.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the return type of `SampleQuery` method of `DataTable`.

```
//Instance method
public class Test
{
 public DataTable SampleQuery(string tablename)
 {
    DataTable dataTable=null;
    ....
    return dataTable;
 }
//or design a static method
 public static DataTable StaticSampleQuery(string tablename)
 {
    DataTable dataTable=null;
    ....
    return dataTable;
 }
}
```

In winform, use static or instance method.

```
//Instance method
Test obj=new Test();
dataGridView1.Datasource=obj.SampleQuery("tableName");

//Static method
dataGridView1.Datasource=Test.StaticSampleQuery("tableName");
```

Answer (score 1):

return Datatable from sqlclass and assign that datatable as datasource of grid

```
     public DataTable SampleQuery(string tablename)
            {
                DataTable dataTable;

                string query = "SELECT * FROM " + tablename;

                //Open connection
                if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
                {
                    adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query,connection);

                    dataTable =  new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(dataTable);

                    //close Connection
                    this.CloseConnection();
                    return dataTable;
                }
              return dataTable;
            }
```

Assign datatable as datasource

```
dataGridView.DataSource = SampleQuery("tablename");
```

Comment: should the datagridview call the samplequery with ("tablename")? since tablename is only the name of the table which the content already in dataTable